# Android: Fixed Width in Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, multiple-columns, fixed, android-layout-weight

I have the following layout

```
LinearLayout
    orientation:horizontal

    CheckBox
        visibility:invisible
        layout_weight:0

    TextView
        layout_weight:1

    TextView
        layout_weight:1

    TextView
        layout_weight:1

    TextView
        layout_weight:1
```

I have an EDIT button in my ActionBar when clicked makes the CheckBox VISIBLE

The problem is that when the checkbox is shown all the TextViews are shifted to the right,

Is there any way I can make the CheckBox column a fixed width so that it wont affect the other parts?

Comment: Have you tried setting layout_weight:1 for the checkbox yet?

Comment: Just remove all the layout_weight, it has no use if they are all the same.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn The layout_weight makes the columns have a fixed width and stretch across the layout when the size is changed.

Comment: @ChrisConway Yes I have tried setting the layout_weight:1 for the checkbox and it's worse because it takes up more space.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and it would not have jump when made visible:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you are at any time, making the visibility of your checkbox gone it will not "reserve" its space.